# How to wire up a RT314F12 latching relay?

Tags: relay

I want to automate the lights in my house. To do this, I want to use a latching relay, so it will only use current when switching. I found a quite cheap latching relay [RT314F12](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/418/NG_DS_RT1_bistable_0717-728101.pdf) but I do not know how to wire it up to for example an Arduino. Can any one please give a wiring example?

Thanks

Comment: Please give a link to the relay datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy a module that uses a bistable relay [Latching/Bistable Relay module 12V](http://www.ebay.com/itm/latching-bistable-relay-module-12v-relay-board-for-avr-pic-arduino-from-eu/181276052335?hash=item2a34e50b6f). Or build a similar scheme ([page 5](http://www.audiowind.com/pdf/D-151.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got stuck on the datasheet (lower right graph on page 8). I thought one had to apply different voltage levels to switch the relay.